# Installing rpm & dependencies

Tags: database, linux, oracle-database, dependencies, rpm

I am trying to install an rpm, namely the Oracle 10g database for CentOS 6 for testing an app.

The problem is that the machine the OS is installed on does not have access to the internet and there is a list of dependencies that the 10g needs which also have other library dependencies.

With 'yum' being unhelpful in this case, is there somewhere or a way dependencies for an rpm can be downloaded without having download each one individually?

Comment: Do you have the required packages on a local medium (e.g. CD, DVD, etc.)?  `rpm -i --aid <main Oracle RPM>` should help.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have the 10g package and not the package for the dependencies.